# VBIDE.CodeModule.DeleteLines procedure not working

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to add data to a new workbook code module from the existing workbook. I have most of the code operating well, but for some reason my .deletelines event is not working. I am trying to delete the existing lines in the Workbook_Open event procedure (This workbook is a copy of a workbook with an existing procedure and I want a different new procedure). And this code won't delete the lines. However, when i get rid of this line, it just creates a new Workbook_Open event procedure, and then I have two and I get an error. This is my code so far.

```
'make data chart
Dim y As Workbook
Dim z As Workbook
Dim y1 As Worksheet
Dim z1 As Worksheet

Set y = Workbooks.Open(sPath)
Set z = Workbooks.Open("P:\HQ INVENTORY\Test Charts\Acs Pull-Chart to edit.xlsm")
Set y1 = y.Worksheets("ACS Pull-Chart to edit")
Set z1 = Workbooks("ACS Pull-Chart to edit.xlsm").Worksheets("ACS Pull-Chart to 
edit")

'add code to new workbook
Dim xPro As VBIDE.VBProject
Dim xCom As VBIDE.VBComponent
Dim xMod As VBIDE.CodeModule
Dim xLine As Long

With y
    Set xPro = .VBProject
    Set xCom = xPro.VBComponents("ACSWorkbook")
    Set xMod = xCom.CodeModule

    With xMod
        xLine = .DeleteLines(.CountOfLines - 3, 3)
        xLine = .CreateEventProc("Open", "Workbook")
        xLine = xLine + 1
        .InsertLines xLine, "   Dim y As Workbook"
        xLine = xLine + 1
        .InsertLines xLine, "   Dim z As Workbook"
        xLine = xLine + 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that I needed the .DeleteLines event on its own line and so established the line number previously by setting xline=88(the number of the line) and then the next line below .DeleteLines xline

```
    With xMod
        xLine = 88
        .InsertLines xLine, ""
        xLine = xLine + 1
        .DeleteLines xLine
        .InsertLines xLine, "   Dim y As Workbook"
        xLine = xLine + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, trying to use `.delete` and `.insertLines.`

First I thought `ThisWorkbook` had some kind of permission stopping me from use both commands.

Even my code was fine, when getting to `.delete` line, the debugger suddenly stopped and raised a dialog box with text: `"Interruption points cannot be inserted"` which was awkward, giving me the options Terminate or Continue. When I decided to Continue, next warning was raising `error 40036`.

I tried solution from Expert Exchange:

```
 'from VBA window go to: Debug > Compile VBAProject
 'then try to fix any error raised
```

By doing these steps, debugging and repairing any, even unrelated errors, I got to solve `error 40036`. My problem was probably related to old Subs containing old functions where some of them were even deleted or with different names, and also related with unfinished structures in functions I created years ago.

**Credits to Yani** in answer related to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24690421/vba-xlsm-file-has-error-40036-with-similar-sheet-names)