# Why I get a RunTime Error on my Excel code?

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error

While running my VBA code the error 40036 occures in line `If LCase(ws.Name) = LCase(Target.Value) Then.`
The code should insert a new table when a new cell is filled with a value.
The new inserted table should have the same name as the inserted value. The template that should be inserted is named "Vorlage".

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)

Dim ws As Object
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
If Target.Row >= 8 And Target.Column = 1 Then
    If MsgBox("Tabelenblatt mit Name """ & Target.Value & """ anlegen ?", _
        vbYesNo, "Blatt Vorlage kopieren") = vbYes Then
        
        For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
            If LCase(ws.Name) = LCase(Target.Value) Then
                MsgBox "Blatt mit dem eingegeben Namen existiert bereits!"
                GoTo ende
            End If
        Next
        
        Worksheets("Vorlage").Copy before:=Worksheets("Vorlage")
        ActiveSheet.Name = Target.Value
'      Me.Activate
    End If
End If

ende:
Set ws = Nothing
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Any ideas to fix it? Some hours ago the code worked without problems...

Comment: If Target is more than a single cell then you can’t compare its Value to a string

Comment: @TimWilliams Shouldn't he get the message error in the previous line `MsgBox("Tabelenblatt mit Name """ & Target.Value & """ anlegen ?", vbYesNo, "Blatt Vorlage kopieren")` then? And wouldn't that be RTE 13 then?

Comment: Can you compile your workbook? Choose Debug > Compile VBA Project in the VBA editor. Maybe read this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/24690421/16578424

Comment: @Storax - yes that's what I'd have expected.

Answer (score 0):

As stated by @Tim Williams, if you are modifying/selecting multiple cells at once, the code will error out.

Also, set you should try to fully qualify and set all of your worksheet objects.

Try the slightly modified code below (debugged and tested)

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)


Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim VolrageSht As Worksheet
Dim C As Range

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

' set the worksheet object
Set VolrageSht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Vorlage")

' loop over target (in case you have multiple cells selected)
For Each C In Target.Cells
    If C.Row >= 8 And C.Column = 1 Then
        If MsgBox("Tabelenblatt mit Name """ & C.Value & """ anlegen ?", _
            vbYesNo, "Blatt Vorlage kopieren") = vbYes Then
            
            For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets  ' <-- In case you have multiple Excel files opne, Use the MACRO workbook
                If LCase(ws.Name) = LCase(C.Value) Then
                    MsgBox "Blatt mit dem eingegeben Namen existiert bereits!"
                    GoTo ende
                End If
            Next ws
            
            VolrageSht.Copy Before:=VolrageSht
            ActiveSheet.Name = C.Value
        End If
    End If
Next C

ende:

Set ws = Nothing
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```